# How to rollback data mart update if data quality checks are not passed?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, rollback

Good afternoon!

I am working with Oracle database. I have a PL/SQL procedure which is scheduled with DBMS job to update every night a table `SOME_TABLE`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROC
IS 
START_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

START_DATE := trunc(add_months(trunc(sysdate), -2), 'MM');

-- delete data for last 3 months and insert updated data for last 3 months

DELETE FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE 1=1
AND VALUE_DAY >= START_DATE;

INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE

SELECT ...
FROM OTHER_TABLE

...

;

COMMIT;

END;
```

I want to make some basic data quality checks for this table (number of null values in columns etc). So my question is:

What is the best way to design data quality checks and the procedure `MY_PROC` itself to test data quality of the table `SOME_TABLE` after update and rollback the update if data quality checks are not passed?

Comment: Ideally you would perform your checks on the source data *before* performing the delete and insert operations. Are you performing an insert-as-select? What kind of quality issues might you have that wouldn't be accounted for in the selection of your data? That said, you can perform whatever checks you want and rollback the entire transaction at any point until you commit.

Comment: 1. Yes, I am performing insert-as-select.

Comment: 2. Kinds of quality issues: nulls in source data in select.

Comment: Another issue. Consider the following example. Source table has countries where the clients live and has no primary keys for these countries. I want to insert into my `SOME_TABLE` primary keys of country where the client lives. The dimension table for countries might miss some countries which exist in the source table. So I want to check that every country in the source table has primary key in country dimension. The problem is that source table with clients and countries is very large and I it's very 'costly' to look for country' primary keys  in country dimension using source table.

Comment: Another issue. I modify some strings from source tables and use modified strings in `group by` statement while doing insert-as-select. I want to check whether after modification of initial data I end with nulls in my `SOME_TABLE`. In other words, I want to check if I am not missing some cases when modifying strings from source table.

Comment: Don't rely on rollback for data quality decisions, it's expensive, ties up resources and holds concurrency mechanisms for potentially long periods if your data size is large. Instead, compare your incoming data to the existing data and decide what to do with it first before doing any delete or insert. And if your concerned about the delete and/or insert itself, don't be. There is no need to second-guess that Oracle's going to correctly do the work we ask it to do. Lastly, once you transition to pre-checks rather than rollbacks, consider partitioning so you can simply truncate parts and append.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an approach that logically separates the delete/insert from the quality checks so that you can organize your code efficiently, perhaps something like this:

```
create or replace function pre_check() return number as
begin
    [perform checks here]
    [if checks pass then return 1, else return 0]
end;

create or replace function post_check() return number as
begin
    [perform checks here]
    [if checks pass then return 1, else return 0]
end;

create or preplace procedure load_data() as
begin
    -- delete data for last 3 months and insert updated data for last 3 months
    DELETE FROM SOME_TABLE
    WHERE 1=1
    AND VALUE_DAY >= START_DATE;

    INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE
    SELECT ...
    FROM OTHER_TABLE
end;

begin
    if pre_check() = 1 then
        load_data();

        if post_check() = 1 then
            commit;
        else
            rollback;
        end if;
    end if;
end;
```

In this way, the transaction control (commit or rollback) is separated from the actual DML. You can write separate functions to perform your quality checks, and skip, rollback, or commit your DML as necessary in the control procedure.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the solution I was looking for.